# Trouble with modular program. Runs only one line ( no error messages .____. )

Tags: c#, debugging, module

I am working on a modular program that calculates income tax due. In my head it makes sense but my program only runs one line of code and then just stops ... no error messages no nothing. I have a feeling it has something to do with the while loops in my CalculateTaxDue class

The program has to:
a) to get valid input from the user ( in one class )
b) calculate the tax due (in another class)
c) display the taxable income as entered by the user, the tax due according to the flat rate, the tax due according to the variable percentage and the total tax due (in yet another class)

Here is my program thus far. I feel like it should run properly but it does not.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // declare variables
        double taxableIncome, incomeTaxDue, flatRate, variablePercentage;

        // get user input
        taxableIncome = GetTaxableInput.GetDouble("Please enter your total income: ");

        // calculate tax due
        incomeTaxDue = CalculateTaxDue.GetTaxableIncome(taxableIncome);

        // display taxable income
        DisplayTaxRate.DisplayTaxableIncome("Your total income is: ", taxableIncome);

        // display flat rate
        flatRate = CalculateTaxDue.GetFlatRate(taxableIncome);
        DisplayTaxRate.DisplayFlatRate("Your tax rate is: ", flatRate);

        // display variable percentage
        variablePercentage = CalculateTaxDue.GetVariablePercentage(taxableIncome);
        DisplayTaxRate.DisplayVariablePercentage("Your variable percentage is: ", variablePercentage);

        // display total tax due
        DisplayTaxRate.DisplayTotalTaxDue("Your total income tax due is: ", incomeTaxDue);

        // keep console open
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class GetTaxableInput
{
    public static double GetDouble(string message)
    {
        // declare variable
        double result;
        // ask for input
        Console.Write(message);
        // capture and validate the user input
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input ");
            Console.Write(message);
        };
        return result;
    }
}

class CalculateTaxDue
{
    public static double GetTaxableIncome(double taxableIncome)
    {
        double incomeTaxDue;
        double flatRate;
        double variablePercentage;

        // calculate and return total income tax due.
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out incomeTaxDue))
        {

            if (taxableIncome < 0)
            {
                flatRate = 0;
                variablePercentage = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 49999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.05;
                flatRate = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 99999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.07;
                flatRate = 2500;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome > 100000)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.09;
                flatRate = 6000;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
        }
        return incomeTaxDue;
    }

    // calculate and return the tax rate
    public static double GetFlatRate(double taxableIncome)
    {
        double incomeTaxDue;
        double flatRate;
        double variablePercentage;

        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out flatRate))
        {

            if (taxableIncome < 0)
            {
                flatRate = 0;
                variablePercentage = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 49999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.05;
                flatRate = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 99999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.07;
                flatRate = 2500;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome > 100000)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.09;
                flatRate = 6000;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
        }
        return flatRate;
    }

    // calculate and return the variable percentage ( tax rate )
    public static double GetVariablePercentage(double taxableIncome)
    {
        double incomeTaxDue;
        double flatRate;
        double variablePercentage;

        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out variablePercentage))
        {

            if (taxableIncome < 0)
            {
                flatRate = 0;
                variablePercentage = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 49999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.05;
                flatRate = 0;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome < 99999)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.07;
                flatRate = 2500;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
            else if (taxableIncome > 100000)
            {
                variablePercentage = 0.09;
                flatRate = 6000;
                incomeTaxDue = taxableIncome * variablePercentage + flatRate;
            }
        }
        return variablePercentage;
    }
}

class DisplayTaxRate
{
    public static void DisplayTaxableIncome(string message, double numberValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:c}", message, numberValue);
    }
    public static void DisplayFlatRate(string message, double numberValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:c}", message, numberValue);
    }
    public static void DisplayVariablePercentage(string message, double numberValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:P}", message, numberValue);
    }
    public static void DisplayTotalTaxDue(string message, double numberValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:c}", message, numberValue);
    }
}
```

There it is. Like i said before, i get no error messages so im not sure where to begin.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code in debug mode?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what the program does that is different from what you expect.  Does it produce any output at all?  Does it given any sign that it has accepted the input you are trying to give?

Comment: The code you've posted is not helpful - we need to see the code that doesn't terminate. Stepping through your program in a debugger or adding some debug logging statements will help you to locate the problem area.

Comment: Why does your GetTaxableIncome method wait for input?  Isn't just supposed to do the calculation and return the value?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a while loop to get input in my calculations class for some reason:/ Thanks to Chris Dunaway! Works like a charm now.